# Balancing between max depth and number of estimators or number of rounds

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

This is a theoretical question for xgb and gradient boosting in general. How can I find out what is the best balance of max_depth and num_rounds or n_estimators. Obviously more max_depth creates complex models which is not recommended in boosting, but hundreds of rounds of boosting can also lead to over fitting the training data. Assuming  CV gives me same mean/std for max_depth 5 and num_rounds 1000 vs max_depth 15 and num_rounds 100 - which one should I use when releasing the model for unknown data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory one could go for providing generalization bounds for these models, but the problem is - they are extremely loose. Thus having smaller upper bound does not really guarantee better scores. In practise, the best approach is to make your generalization estimate more reliable - you are using 10-CV? Use 10x10 CV (ten random shuffles of 10CV), if it still gives no answer, use 100. At some point you will get a winner. Furthermore, if you are actually going to realease model to public maybe expected value is not the best metric? CV usually reports mean value (expected value) - so instead of looking only at this - look at the whole spectrum of results obtained. Two values with the same mean and different std clearly show what to choose. When both means and stds are the same you can look at min of the score (which will capture "worst case" scenario), etc.

To sum up: take a close look at the scores, not just averages - and repeat evaluation multiple times to make this reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I will take that as an answer. I was wondering if monitoring the errors on a random sample (may be 10% of the data), after each round would help. Or may be how the validation loss changes after every round. Say if I (by having a large early stopping of 200 in xgboost, I do not know how to do it in sklearn) plot the number of rounds the validation loss increases after every decrease, can I firmly say that the model which has that line under all other lines will be better ?

Comment: Area under such curve will not give you a good selector, as in the end you use just a final model, it does not matter if previously it was a bad one.

Comment: Hi - I was not thinking about area. It is more like this - say model 1 has these values

Comment: I was not thinking about area. I am plotting num of rounds vs num of rounds needed for error to reduce. Ex (for max_depth 15) 1-0,2-0,3-0,4-1,6-1,8-2,11-2,14-2,17-3 ... 51-inf (i.e 51st round is the lowest value of test-eval). Another ex may be (for lower max_depth) 1-0,2-0 ..... 99-0, 100-1,103-1,105-0,106-0,107-3,111-3 and so on till may be 150-INF. If I plot these two lines (in a scaled fashion) and the second line remains under the first line - can that mean it is a better model ? with the logic "a model reducing test eval after several rounds may be leaking class information in training"?